# how do I replace and update intel i910 chipset driver in ubuntu-9.04

Tags: 10.04, drivers, intel, 9.04, vga

I have a question about vga driver issue,
I am now have ubuntu-9.04 with linux-kernel-2.6.28 install in my machine.
My machine has intel i910 chipset.
And I found that when I use the external monitor, I can't work with extension mode at my second display.

Then I also try ubuntu-10.04 at the same machine which has i910 chipset.
It works well when I use external monitor. I can use mirror mode and extension mode at second display.

The big problem for me is, I have a application that works only for ubuntu-9.04 with kernel-2.6.28.
So I can't change the ubuntu version to 10.04.

Can I just change the intel vga driver in 9.04?
How to do it?
Is it possible to use the intel vga driver which build-in 10.04 in 9.04?

Thanks for your kindly help !

Answer (score 1):

A ppa with the newest drivers can [be found here](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver).

Add it with `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver` and after that do `sudo apt-get update` and a `sudo apt-get upgrade` install the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` using the command `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`.

Those are the most recent Intel drivers, it should work in 9.04 the same way it works on 10.04.